# msg.sender not recognized

Tags: solidity, msg.sender

I am getting the following error for the code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7 ;

contract Variables {
   //Global variables
   uint public pubInt = 25;
   bool public truth = false;
   string public msg = "Hello World";

   function dosomething() public{
       uint8 v = 30;
       address sender = msg.sender;
   }

}
```

**TypeError: Member "sender" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string storage ref.
--> Web3/Variables.sol:12:25:
|
12 |        address sender = msg.sender;**

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring a state variable with the reserved keyword `msg`:

```js
string public msg = "Hello World";
```

You don't want to do that. You should not try to declare variables that are reserved keywords of the Solidity language, like `msg` which is globally available. So you are effectively 'overriding' it or shadowing it.

Better declare it like:

```js
string public message = "Hello World";
```

The whole code would look like this:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7 ;

contract Variables {
   //Global variables
   uint public pubInt = 25;
   bool public truth = false;
   string public message = "Hello World";

   function dosomething() public {
       uint8 v = 30;
       address sender = msg.sender;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7 ;

contract Variables {
   //Global variables
   uint public pubInt = 25;
   bool public truth = false;
   string public message = "Hello World"; // msg is a special global variable that needs to have a property or don't use it

   function dosomething() public{
       uint8 v = 30;
       address sender = msg.sender; // msg has a property called "sender"
   }
}
```